# How do I include parent template from any directory in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

When I have child template for example **index.scala.html** and parent template **main.scala.html**, and I am including parent template using code:

```
@main("MyApp") {}
```

this template is including correctly. But when I move **index.scala.html** into directory, for example `Location` and trying to include parent template using code:

```
@views.main("MyApp") {}
```

it does not work.

[image: index.scala.html]

Structure of my `views` directory:

[image: structure]

I am getting error:

```
[error] /Users/dev/project/app/scala/pl/moody/views/Location/index.scala.html:1: object main is not a member of package views
[error] @views.main("Moody") {
[error]        ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found working solution. The correct compiled html file is placed under `target` directory. 
In my case `target/scala-2.11/twirl/main/scala/com/myProject/views/html/main.template.scala`

Given I have this directory now I am able to add it to my `index.scala.html` and it will looks

```scala
@scala.com.myProject.views.html.main("MyApp") {

}
```

and the same url will be rendering html from controller:

```scala
  def index = Action {
    Ok(scala.com.myProject.views.html.main("MyApp"))
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `views` prefix, it is auto-imported, so you should use just `@main("MyApp")` even if children are placed in subdirectories.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I think both solutions could work. I think it is something in IntelliJ, because even I have `@main("MyApp")` in the template, and it works, IDE shows message `cannot resolve symbol main`

Answer (score 1):

I had almost the same problem, I solved that by calling it with the full path like so:

```
@views.html.admin("Admin Interface") {

}
```

Try calling it like:

```
@views.html.main("MyApp") {}
```